# Why hasn't 'typedef struct' been made optional in C?

Tags: c, struct, standards, typedef

In C, a struct can be defined, typedefed, and declared as such:

```
typedef struct {
    int bar;
} Foo;
Foo foo;
```

Or:

```
struct Foo {
    int bar;
} foo;
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```

I think this is a bit inconsistent and overly verbose. I would like for it to work as in C++.

In C++, you don't need to specify `typedef struct Foo Foo;` to be able to declare a struct like `Foo foo;` instead of `struct Foo foo;`. Why hasn't this been introduced to the C standard, or as a compiler flag option? Are there any examples of C code that would break if `typedef struct` were to be made optional in C?

Comment: You could always use structs like they were *meant to be used*, and say `struct Foo foo;` to declare your variables.

Comment: Even though not normal, we can easily create a code which can be broken. `struct {...} Foo; typedef struct Foo Foo2; typedef struct {} Foo;` Now if tyoedef is made optional you have two types of `Foo`

Comment: @knightrider: What do you mean? If the two object declarations are not identical, you get a warning. And `Foo` is nowhere a type, but a variable declaration if you remove the `typedef`.

Comment: Because C and C++ are different languages? Why does `const` have different semantics, why ... ?

Comment: @oalf I made a small mistake. Lets look at this 1. `struct Foo{...}`; 2. `typedef struct Foo Foo2`. 3. `typedef struct { }....`. So what are the types here? `struct Foo` (from 1), `Foo2` (from 2), `Foo` (from 3). Now as he asks lets make typedef optional. so now what are the types? `Foo` (from 1), `Foo 2` from (2), and again `Foo` from 3. So if you make typedef option it can potentially break code

Comment: "I would like for it to work as in C++" If people made all languages the same, they woudn't be suitable for every task (and of course there would be no reason to have them all).

Answer (score 8):

It *is* optional.

```
struct mystruct {
    int x;
};

struct mystruct y;
```

The struct definitions are in a separate namespace for "tag" names.  This is so they don't collide with function or variable names, so you can do things like this:

```
struct stat st;
int r = stat("/path/file.txt", &st);
```

You notice how `stat` is the name of a function and the name of a struct, but they don't collide?  This is a real example, see [stat (2)](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat).  If you eliminated this, old code would fail to compile.  The `typedef` creates a name in the same namespace as functions and variables.

```
struct stat { ... };
int stat(const char *path, struct stat *buf);
typedef struct stat stat; // ERROR
```

Some style guides advocate *not* using typedefs, and simply typing `struct stat` everywhere.  Whether or not you agree with this, it is existing practice in various places (such as the Linux kernel!) and the C standards committee is opposed to breaking existing C code bases.

In C++, compatibility with C code is maintained by making `struct` optional, but if you define a function with the same name as a struct you will need to use `struct` explicitly in variable definitions:

```
stat st; // error! stat is a function
struct stat st; // Ok
int r = stat("/path/file.txt", &st);
```

Answer (score 3):

Well, you have this:

```
struct Foo {
    int bar;
} foo;
typedef struct Foo Foo;
```

In the first line you are defining the identifier `Foo` within the struct name space (not in the C++ sense). You can use it and define variables or function arguments of the newly defined type by defining the type of the argument as `struct Foo`:

```
void f(struct Foo argument);
```

In the function above, struct is required.
The second line adds a type alias `Foo` in the global name space and thus allows you to just write:

```
void f(Foo argument);
```

In the function declaration above, struct keyword is no longer needed. Note that since both identifier name spaces are different, defining `Foo` both in the structs and global spaces is not an error, as it is not redefining the same identifier, but rather creating a different identifier in a different place.

To make the difference clearer:

```
typedef struct Foo { 
    int x; 
} Bar;

void Foo() { } // correct

//void Bar() {} // error: symbol Bar already defined as an alias to 'struct Foo'
```

You can define a function with the same name of the struct as the identifiers are kept in different spaces, but you cannot define a function with the same name as a `typedef` as those identifiers collide.

So, the common idiom is using both:

```
typedef struct Foo {
    int bar;
} Foo;
Foo foo;
```

Edit (more informations):

In C++, it is slightly different as the rules to locate a symbol have changed subtly. C++ still keeps the two different identifier spaces, but unlike in C, when you only define the symbol within the class identifier space, you are not required to provide the struct/class keyword. What changes are the search rules, not where the identifiers are defined. The compiler will search the global identifier table and after 'Foo' has not been found it will search for 'Foo' within the class identifiers.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers are free to make extensions but since no compiler has made 
it the committee has no reason to standardize it.

> Are there any examples of C code that would break if typedef struct
>   were to be made optional in C?

Plenty. Consider something like that:

```
struct Foo {
    int bar;
    /* ... */
};

void Foo(void) {
    /* ... */
}
```

It will stop compiling.

Comment: Couldn't the standard or the compiler be adapted so that e.g. `Foo foo;` would be recognized as a struct declaration and `Foo();` would be recognized as a function call?

Comment: @fgsfdsfgts: It would be ambiguous in other places, like in casts: `(Foo)(x)`... because that syntax could also be a function call.